# React Native Reanimated - Animating changes in flex-box?

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I can't get my animated view to change based on the state of the keyboard. Is there something that prevents animations like this? When I include something like the background color changing based on the keyboard, it works fine. Here's a mockup of what I've been working on.

```
const animKeyboard = useAnimatedKeyboard();

const determineFlex = (height:number) => {
   'worklet'
   return height > 0 ? 'flex-end' : 'center'
}

const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(()=> {
  return {
    justifyContent: determineFlex(animKeyboard.height.value)
  }
}

<Animated.View style={animatedStyle}>
   ...
</Animated.View>
```